# Range alternative in Intersect at Excel Events VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I was knowing before how create that code in case of determining a specific array to implement a function in it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:O7000")) Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "Hi"
 End If
End Sub
```

So **Intersect** here works only when I write inside Argument2 **Range** function.
I don't want to determine whole that array. When I want to develop this code by this shape:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim SafeTbl As ListObject
  Set SafeTbl = ListObjects("Safe")
   If Not Intersect(Target, SafeTbl.Range.Address) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Hi"
   End If
End Sub
```

I find this `Type mismatch` compile error:

[image: Type Mismatch Error]

I don't know why this error exists. While I see that my development is making same as previous code does. **As this code is determining only array has data.**

Comment: `.address` is a string, you can only intersect ranges so leave it as `SafeTbl.Range`

Comment: Remove `.Address`. The address -property returns the address of a Range as String. You want to check the Range itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, `.Address` is a string. The Intersect method requires ranges as the parameters, not the text of the range address, which you are currently providing.

The `Type mismatch` compile error is telling you that the "variable or property isn't of the correct type" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-mismatch-error-13)

Microsoft says:

> [Application.Intersect method (Excel)] Returns a Range object that
> represents the rectangular intersection of two or more ranges.

To be explicit, this means your code needs changing to this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim SafeTbl As ListObject
  Set SafeTbl = ListObjects("Safe")
   If Not Intersect(Target, SafeTbl.Range) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Hi"
   End If
End Sub
```

More can be read about the Intersect method here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect

And also more about the Range property here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.range

**Update** 
As @BigBen correctly points out, in your case, we are actually referring to the `ListObject.Range` property, so the further information on this is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.range